# How to start an animation on an object on clicking another object in a-frame?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe, webvr

I am making a project on WebVR using a-frame in which I have loaded a collada model of a banner and an a-box element. I want to rotate the box about its axis when the model is clicked upon. I used javascript but instead of animating, it just rotated the box directly very unlike to what happens when we use animation tag of a-frame.

```js
<script>

    function changeView() {
        var view = document.getElementById("float");
        view.setAttribute("rotation",
        {
            x: 0,
            y: 360,
            z: 0      
        });
    }
</script>
```

```html
<a-scene>
  
  <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="floatingbanner" src="models/floatingbanner.dae"></a-asset-item>
  </a-assets>
  
  <a-entity id="float" collada-model="#floatingbanner" position="-2 2 0" scale="0.3 0.3 0.3" onclick="loaddoc()">
  </a-entity>

  <a-box id="box" position="-1 1.5 0" onclick="changeView()" height=".3" depth=".3" width=".3"></a-box>
 
  <a-camera id="view" position="0 0 0">
          <a-cursor color="black"/>
  </a-camera>

<a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`<a-animation></a-animation>`](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/core/animations.html).

Define a animation:

```
<a-entity>
  <a-entity position="5 0 0"></a-entity>
  <a-animation attribute="rotation"
               dur="10000"
               fill="forwards"
               to="0 360 0"
               begin="startAnimation"
               repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
</a-entity>
```

And then `emit()` the `begin` event like this :

```
function changeView() {
    var view = document.getElementById("float");
    view.emit("startAnimation");
}
```

---

Also try to use the component system, by attaching the script to Your entities:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo',{
  init:function(){
  var view = document.getElementById("float");
     this.el.addEventListener('click',function(){
         view.emit("startAnimation");
     });
  }
});
```

Comment: Using the above, seems to make sense, but cannot implement it:  https://jsfiddle.net/RonK/hqrk4e5w/33/ . Any ideas whats wrong? Setting each to rotate with "click" works fine on themselves. I'm Trying to get each one to activate the other.